# When using promises why is the last then called?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hf1T_AONQJU)(code around 36 minutes) on Promises, but I'm confused by a bit of code:

```
getUser('mjackson')
.then(getTweets)
.then(updateStatus)
.then(undefined, handleError);
```

My problem with understand this is why is the last `then` called? And why does it pass `undefined` as the first argument?

If `getTweets()` fails, then `updateStatus()` is never called. Which is why I'm confused as to why the last `then` is called if the second (the one that contains `updateStatus()`) isn't.

I know `handleError` is a callback, I just don't get why `undefined` is passed.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think that it is because he want to handle the rejected promise but not do anything to the resolved promise.

Answer (score 5):

Any `then` with a function provided as the second parameter will catch and handle any rejected promises farther up the promise chain.

So if `getUser` or `getTweets` or `updateStatus` fails, the error will be handled in `handleError`.

This code is passing `undefined` as the first parameter because in this case `updateStatus` is the last thing that the person writing it wants to do, and there's nothing more to do if that succeeds.

Most promise libraries, and the ES6 promise standard provide a `.catch(...)` method that is really just a shorthand for `.then(undefined, ...)`:

```
getUser('mjackson')
.then(getTweets)
.then(updateStatus)
.catch(handleError);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of using the promise methods, for async flow control, particularly for error-handling.

The first is:

```
anOperation.then(onsuccess, onerror);
```

The second is:

```
anOperation.catch(onerror);
```

If `onsuccess` is undefined or null in the first case, it means that there is no success option there (so it would move to the success after that one, in the success case).

Most promises you see/use are `.then(onsuccess, undefined)`.

It should be noted:

- If you throw an error in `onsuccess`, the `onerror` does ***not*** get fired. It moves to the next error down. It is impossible to fire both callbacks in the same `.then`, it's an either-or scenario
- If you return a value from a `.catch` or an `onerror` callback, it is expected that you have solved the issue, and thus, you go into the next `onsuccess` of the next `.then`, with the value you returned. If this isn't what you want, rethrow, or return a `Promise.reject`

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the `then` function is:

```
p.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

If you pass `undefined` as the first parameter, it behaves as `p.catch(onRejected);`

In a `then` chain, every success functions will be called in an order unless one failed. If one failed, all the execution will break unless a second parameter of a then exists. The second parameter will behave the catch of any.

If a `then` function returns a promises, you can make a `then` chain. 
`handleError` has called, because one of the previous promises in the chain was failed.

**Promises in a chain with an example**

[Here my JsBin to understand a promise chain](https://jsbin.com/boqago/4/edit?js,console). Try to change `giveMeSuccessPromise` and `giveMeFailPromise` functions in doX or catchX functions.

In a chain of `then` clauses as below:

```
p.then(doFirst)
   .then(doSecond)
   .then(doThird)
   .then(undefined, catchFirstSecondThird)
   .then(doFourth)
   .then(doFifth, catchEveryThing);
```

In this example, in case of any of the *doFirst, doSecond or doThird* failed *catchFirstSecondThird* will be executed. In case of any of the *catchFirstSecondThird, doFourth or doFifth* failed *catchEveryThing* will be executed.

*The order of the execution in happy path:*

> doFirst, doSecond, doThird, doFourth, doFifth

*The order of the execution when only doFirst fails:*

> doFirst, catchFirstSecondThird, doFourth, doFifth

*The order of the execution when only doSecond fails:*

> doFirst, doSecond, catchFirstSecondThird, doFourth, doFifth

*The order of the execution when both doFirst and doFourth fails:*

> doFirst, catchFirstSecondThird, doFourth, catchEveryThing

Resources:

- [From MDN, Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [From MDN, API of `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)
- [From MDN, API of `catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)
- [A very good tutorial about promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)